# Is there way to send image with discord.py bot hosted by heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

Is there a way to save and send photos from a discord.py bot hosted by Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, move your photos to a bot's directory and push them to your GitHub repository. Then deploy the project on heroku. To send a photo (file) use this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send_photo(ctx):
    await ctx.send(discord.File("photo.png"))
```

This command sends a photo called `photo.png`.

To send random photo you can use `random.choice()` function from `random` module:

```py
import random

PHOTOS = ["photo1.png", "photo2.png", "photo3.png"]

@bot.command()
async def send_photo(ctx):
    await ctx.send(discord.File(random.choice(PHOTOS)))
```

Comment: Also remember to use `/` instead of  \ when accessing files in different directory in Heroku.